# Concatenate<T>(List<T> list, string specifiedPropertyOfT)?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, reflection, collections

### From Parameter to Property?

```
public class ConcatenateListTMember
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        var someList = new List<AnyClass>();
        someList.Add(new AnyClass("value1"));
        someList.Add(new AnyClass("value2"));
        Console.WriteLine(Concatenate(someList, "SomeProperty"));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static string Concatenate<T>(List<T> list, string specifiedPropertyOfT)
    {
        string output = String.Empty;
        // TODO: Somehow concatenate all the specified property elements in the list?
        return output;
    }
}

internal class AnyClass
{
    public AnyClass(string someProperty)
    {
        SomeProperty = someProperty;
    }

    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

How might it be possible to implement the generic method in this code sample?

- Please note that `specifiedPropertyOfT` does not have to be a string if the same aim can be achieved using another type.
- Ideally, reflection would not be needed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even better - an extension method:

```
static string Concatenate<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T,string> func)
{
    return String.Join("",list.Select(func));
}
```

Usage:

```
someList.Concatenate(i => i.SomeProperty);
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/runcode?code=LRA78268

Answer (score 5):

I think you're looking for the new overloads of [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx) in .NET 4 which would allow:

```
IEnumerable<AnyClass> sequence = ...;
string joined = string.Join(",", sequence.Select(x => x.SomeProperty));
```

If you can't use a lambda expression to express the property - e.g. because this has to be done at execution time - then you *will* have to use reflection.

Note that the selector in `Select` doesn't have to return strings - `String.Join` will call `ToString` on any non-string values.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. I've created an extension method on IEnumerable:

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static string ConcatinateString<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<T, string> GetValue)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var item in collection)
        {
            sb.Append(GetValue(item));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then so call it, you would use something like this:

```
var values = new List<TestClass>
        {
            new TestClass(){Name="John",Comment="Hello"},
            new TestClass(){Name="Smith", Comment="Word"}
        };
string s = values.ConcatinateString((x => x.Name));
string v = values.ConcatinateString((x => x.Comment));
```

In this example `s = "JohnSmith"` and `v = "HelloWord"`. The Func() gives you flexibility. You are basically telling the function where to go to get the string to concatenate. I also used a StringBuilder in case you are working with long collections.